# Hierarchical memory organization

Tags: memory, computers, rom

[image]

I get everything about this picture perfectly clear, but what I don't understand is where is ROM located? Isn't ROM part of BIOS? Where do we sort BIOS in this memory organization?

Comment: The BIOS is usually in a ROM of some description, but the graphic is simply informative of cost and size of different storage types.

Comment: Look at how it's made ... broadly similar level of technology and storage capacity to small RAMs, so somewhere near the border between "RAM" here (really DRAM) and "Cache" (really SRAM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get everything about this picture perfectly clear, but what I don't understand is where is ROM located? Isn't ROM part of BIOS? Where do we sort BIOS in this memory organization?

Nowhere. It's not part of this hierarchy at all.

The memory hierarchy shown here is for the types of storage that are routinely used to store and retrieve data while a computer is running. The BIOS ROM is not used this way -- it is read from briefly when the computer is booted up, and is only written to as a rare special case during updates.